# Does there exist $u(x)\neq 0$ such that integral is equal to $0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $\theta \in \mathbb R$. Does there a function $u(x)\neq 0$, not depending on $\theta$, such that
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\theta} u(x)(\theta-x) dx = 0 ?$$

I spend much time to try guessing $u(x)$, like $u(x)=x$, $u(x)=x^2$, $u(x)=x^3$, but the integral is not equal $0$.

So does there exist $u(x)\neq 0$ such that integral is equal to $0$?
Is there a way to find $u(x)$ without guessing?

Comment: Yes, u(x) not depend $\theta$.

Comment: Is $\ \theta\ $ a constant, or do you want $\  \displaystyle\int_0^\theta u(x)(\theta-x)xdx =0\ $ to hold for *all* values of $\ \theta\ $?  The only way you can get the latter to be true is to put $\ u(x)=0\ $ for all $\ x\ $ (except for a possible set of measure $0$).

Comment: Yes, $\theta$ is constant and I want for all $\theta$.

Comment: So, you actually want your integral to be zero for all values of $ \theta $ without $u(x)$ being identically $0$

Comment: I would be shocked if such a continuous function exists for general $\theta$ (for specific ones it does... e.g. $\theta = 1$ and $u(x) = \text{sinc}(2\pi(1-x)$), but I can't immediately think of how to prove it. You can rewrite the condition as $\int_0^n u(x) dx = \int_0^n \tfrac{u(x) x}{n} dx$, so you are asking for the average value of $u(x)$ to match the average value of $\tfrac{u(x) x}{n}$ on the domain $[0,n]$. The function $u$ clearly cannot be monotone (else the RHS of the integral equation above will always be smaller), and any perodic function will fail except at inflection points

Comment: I mean $n = \theta$ in the above but cannot edit. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

If $\  \displaystyle\int_0^\theta u(x)(\theta-x)xdx =0\ $ for *all* values of $\ \theta\ $ and $\ u\ $ does not depend on theta, then
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{d}{d\theta} \int_0^\theta u(x)(\theta-x)dx\\
&=u(\theta)(\theta-\theta) + \int_0^\theta u(x)dx\\
&= \int_0^\theta u(x)dx\ .
\end{align}
Now differentiating the equation $\  \displaystyle\int_0^\theta u(x)dx=0\ $ with respect to $\ \theta\ $ gives
$
u(\theta)=0\ 
$.  If $\ u\ $ is continuous, this must be true for all values of $\ \theta\ $. If $\ u\ $ is not required to be continuous, it must still be true with the possible exception of for values of $\ \theta\ $ lying within some set of measure zero.

Comment: Indeed. I was in the middle of writing up an edit of your deleted answer with exactly this, but you fixed your post before I could. Bravo.

Comment: Note the Leibniz Integral Law usually requires some notion of local continuity to hold, which is what you somewhat implicitly allude to at the end of you answer. In the case that $u$ is not continuous on $[0,\theta]$ we can of course find a function $u$ which *does* work. It's also probably worth noting that the lack of dependence of $u$ on $\theta$ is what makes $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} u(x)(\theta-x) = u(x)$ work, since in the case where $u$ *can* depend on $x$ we must use the product rule.

Comment: As far as I recall (I'm too lazy to look it up, except for the relatively weak reassurance given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem#Statement)) all that's required is that $\ u(x)\ $ and $\ xu(x)\ $ be Lebesgue integrable.  In that case, I believe, $\ \int_0^\theta u(x)dx\ $ and  $\ \int_0^\theta xu(x)dx\ $ are almost everywhere differentiable with $\ \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\theta u(x)dx=u(\theta)\ $ and $\ \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\theta xu(x)dx=\theta u(\theta)\ $ almost everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

As $\theta-x$ is a straight line $\int_0^{\theta}\theta-xdx = \frac{\theta^2}{2}$.Now there exists a $c$ in $(0,\theta) $ such that $\int_0^{c}\theta-xdx = \int_c^{\theta}\theta-xdx $ so, now define $u(x) = 1$ for x in $[0,c]$ and $u(x)=-1$ in  $(c,\theta]$ and we have value of  that integral $0$.

Comment: Here $u(x)$ depends on $\theta$

Comment: the required u(x) is independent of $\theta$